# Obtaining a bound on a function given a bound on its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose $f\in C^1([0,1])$ satisfies $f(0)=0$, $|f'(0)| <\infty$ and $|f'(t)| \leq \alpha t^{-1}$ on $(0,1]$ for some fixed positive constant $\alpha$. I would like to show $f$ satisfies a lower bound on $[0,1]$ depending on $t$ and $\alpha$, but *independent* of the value of $f'(0)$.

My guess is that $f(t) \geq c\ln(d)[1-\ln(t+d)]$ for some constants $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $d>0$ depending only on $\alpha$, since this satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t) = -\frac{c\ln(d)}{t+d}$. I tried using the fundamental theorem of calculus: if $x\in(0,1]$ and $\epsilon<x$, then $$f(x) = f(\epsilon) + \int_\epsilon^x f'(t)dt \geq f(\epsilon) - \alpha\int_\epsilon^x t^{-1}dt = f(\epsilon) - \alpha\ln(x) + \alpha \ln(\epsilon).$$

As $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, we have $f(\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$, but the $\ln(\epsilon)$ term blows up. So I'm not really sure how to proceed, or if even such a bound is possible. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For $\alpha=1,\ $ I believe that for any $n\in\mathbb{N},\ f(x)=\ln(1+n x)$ satisfies the conditions and $f$ has no lower bound across all such function (as $n\to\infty).$ And I'm guessing there's a similar analysis for other values of $\alpha.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lower bound with those conditions.

Suppose $\alpha>0$ and note that $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int_\epsilon^1 {\alpha \over t} dt = \infty$. Choose $K>0$ and find $t_0$ such that the integral value is $\ge K$. Let $f'$ be defined as linear interpolation between $(0,0)$ and $(t_0, -{\alpha \over t_0})$ and $-{\alpha \over t}$ subsequently. Then $f(1) \le -K$.

Comment: On the interval $(0,t_0)$, your function satisfies $|f'(t)| = \alpha t/t_0^2 \leq \alpha/t_0$, right? But for $t_0$ small, this won't satisfy $|f'(t)| \leq \alpha t^{-1}$ for all $t$, so I don't think this satisfies the assumptions?

Comment: The function $f'$ satisfies $|f'(t)| \le { \alpha \over t}$, I'm not sure where you got the other part. $f$ is given by integrating $f'$. it does satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: @asmith42422 There is no need to accept the answer if it does not address your question.

Comment: I realised my misunderstanding of your answer, so it does address the question. Thank you

Comment: @asmith42422 Thanks for letting me know!